# string formatting issue when using dictionary value

Tags: python, dictionary, string-formatting

I have a weird problem when trying create a string when using a dictionary value. Basically, I have a function that opens a file, reads a line, and stores the values it finds in that line in a dictionary. Then, it sends those values to an external program. Here is the code:

```
def createLandscapes(file):

  landscapeParameters = {'FILE': "NULL",
                         'N': "NULL",
                         'K': "NULL",
                         'NUM': "100"}

  for line in file:
    if line == "END LANDSCAPES\n":
      break
    else:
      parameters = line.replace(" ", '').split(",")

      for parameter in parameters:
        parameter = parameter.split("=")
        if parameter[0] not in landscapeParameters:
          malformedFile()
        landscapeParameters[parameter[0]] = parameter[1]

      for key in landscapeParameters:
        if landscapeParameters[key] == "NULL":
          malformedFile()

      # This print statment is for diagnostic purposes
      print("./generateScoreTables {} {} {} {}".format(landscapeParameters['FILE'],
                                                       landscapeParameters['N'],
                                                       landscapeParameters['K'],
                                                       landscapeParameters['NUM']))

      os.system("./generateScoreTables {} {} {} {}".format(landscapeParameters['FILE'],
                                                           landscapeParameters['N'],
                                                           landscapeParameters['K'],
                                                           landscapeParameters['NUM']))
```

To make this very clear, the function looks for a series of parameter inputs on a single, comma separated line, in the form of

```
FILE=example, N=20, K=5, NUM=100
```

It takes those inputs and overrides the default inputs (if specified) in `landscapeParameters`, and uses the values in `landscapeParameters` to call an external program.

The strange this is that the string formatting doesn't seem to work correctly when I use the default parameters in `landscapeParameters`. What I mean by this is that if the function reads the line:

```
FILE=example, N=20, K=5, NUM=100
```

Everything works correctly, and the print statement prints:

```
./generateScoreTables example 20 5 100
```

However, if the function reads the line:

```
FILE=example, N=20, K=5
```

Where I've left `NUM` out to use the default parameter, I get the following output instead:

```
./generateScoreTables testland1 15
 0 100
Segmentation fault
sh: 2: 0: not found
```

It appears that format is not formatting this string correctly, but I don't understand why. Does anyone have any insight into this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: @Prune What exactly would you like me to add? The problem should be readily apparent and easily reproducible from information provided.

Comment: Attach the demonstrative input file that produces the error -- perhaps only two lines.  Edit your code to the *minimal* code that will reproduce the error.  Perhaps it's no more than a one-line call.

Comment: @Prune Why would I attach an input file when I'm not going to provide the necessary and irrelevant 50 lines of code needed to process that file? I provided the example input needed to reproduce the error. And if I knew the exact cause of the error, I wouldn't be on here would I? I'm trying to diagnose this myself at the moment but for now I'm simply aware that the above code creates the described error. It might be a programmer error that I simply haven't noticed. If my description is unclear I will be glad to clarify, but I feel like you're just being obtuse.

Comment: You've been lucky. Someone took pity and answered. @Prune is a long-time member here who is trying to explain the ropes to you. Usually you might find that people will become impatient reading through a lot of verbiage and code like that.

Comment: @user1105224: briefly, because it's *your* job to make it easy for us to start debugging your problem.  Your posted code fails to run, even with a constructed input file.

Comment: @BillBell: Thanks for the support.  Some people take a different path to learning debugging and filing problem reports.  OP is doing well enough, on a trajectory to become a fully functional SO citizen.

Answer (score 2):

The problem has already been pointed out to you, but I'm still unable to comment so I'll leave this separate. This would involve reworking your code a little bit.

Once you get to this stage:

```
parameters = ['FILE=example', 'N=20', 'K=5', 'NUM=100']

# make a list of tuples with [(FILE, default), ('N', 20)...]
pars = [x.split("=") for x in parameters]
```

Now convert each twople into a Key, value pair in a dictionary dict_of_pars

```
dict_of_pars = {k: v for k, v in pars}
#dictionary with values for a single line
# {'FILE': 'example', 'N': '20', 'K': '5', 'NUM': '100'}
```

At this point you will have a dictionary containing all defined parameters for any particular line. If you make a function (that outputs) that holds default values you can send the available arguments for a line using **dict_of_pars in the call

```
# define output function with default parameters
def output(FILE='example, N='n', K='k', NUM='num'):
      os.system(FILE, N, K, NUM)
```

Now you can call the function using

```
  output(**dict_of_pars)  #will unpack the arguments into output function
```

Made one of these temporary dictionaries for each line in the file, pass it to the output. Hope this helps.

Comment: Sure, I get what you are saying. But do you have any understanding as to why the string formatting doesn't work as described in my question? I tried implementing a new dictionary every loop to prevent possible bogus values (even though this shouldn't be a problem as I was only running the code on one input line) but I still ended up with incorrect string formatting. It seems rather over-complicated to have to write an extra function for nothing else other than formatting string values from a dictionary.

Comment: I've just had a good look through and can't find your problem, it prints correctly. The code should run as expected as long as you define the dictionary just after the 'for line in ' statement. Other then this I can't help, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt. I've actually narrowed it down on my own to the point where I'm pretty sure I've run across a bug in Python. It's just not that important for my program and I don't have the time to deal with it right now, so I've just abandoned it and used another implementation.

Answer (score -1):

You're updating the same variable on every loop, so if it reads one line that doesn't have a particular field it will use the value from the last time it read it.

Instead declare an empty dictionary inside the loop and use the `.get` function to have a default value if the key doesn't exist in the dictionary.

```
def createLandscapes(file):
    params = ['FILE','N','K','NUM']

    for line in file:
        if line == "END LANDSCAPES\n":
            break
        else:
            landscapeParameters = {}
            parameters = line.replace(" ", '').split(",")

            for parameter in parameters:
                parameter = parameter.split("=")
                if parameter[0] not in params:
                    malformedFile()
                landscapeParameters[parameter[0]] = parameter[1]

                for key in landscapeParameters:
                if landscapeParameters[key] == "NULL":
                    malformedFile()
         os.system("./generateScoreTables {} {} {} {}".format(landscapeParameters.get('FILE',''),
                                                           landscapeParameters.get('N',''),
                                                           landscapeParameters.get('K',''),
                                                           landscapeParameters.get('NUM',100)))
```

You'll probably need to tweak this a little bit, but it should give you more predictable results.

Comment: I just tried this, but I still end up with the same result described.